# While using React Context API ,unable to fetch data

Tags: reactjs

> This is my App.js , I am using context api but I am unable to fetch
>   data at {context.country} and {context.job} which is in child
>   component i.e Neighbour. 
>   This is my App.js , I am using context api but I am unable to fetch 
>   data at {context.country} and {context.job} which is in child
>   component i.e Neighbour.
>   App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Neighbour from './Neighbour';

    const MyContext = React.createContext();

    class MyProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        firstName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Holland', age: 24, country: 'America', job: 'Actor',
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <MyContext.Provider value={{
            state: this.state, growOld: () => this.setState({ age: this.state.age + 1 })
          }}>
            {this.props.children}
          </MyContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }


    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <MyProvider value={{ state: this.state }}>
              <div>
                <p>I am in App component</p>
                <Family />
                <br />
                <Neighbour />
              </div>
            </MyProvider>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

> Neighbour.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const MyContext = React.createContext();

class Neighbour extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyContext.Consumer>
                    {context => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <p>Country : {context.country}</p>
                            <p>Job : {context.job}</p>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                </MyContext.Consumer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Neighbour;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are providing the value as object `{state: this.state}` to context, you need to use it like `context.state.country` in your consumer.

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <p>Country : {context.state.country}</p>
                        <p>Job : {context.state.job}</p>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
```

or you Provide the value in provider like

```
 <MyProvider value={this.state}>
          <div>
            <p>I am in App component</p>
            <Family />
            <br />
            <Neighbour />
          </div>
  </MyProvider>
```

Also in `Neighbour` component you re creating a context again which doesn't have a `Provider` and hence the value in Consumer would come undefined, you need to import the same context that you have used the `Provider` on

In Neighbour.js

Neighbour.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
inport { MyContext } from 'path/to/context';
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at      <p>Country : {context.state.country}</p>

Comment: 'path/to/context' which path is it

Comment: MyContext is defined in App.js and hence the path to App.js is the path, however it will have a cyclic dependency since Neighbour is being used in App.js, so its better that you create MyContext in a separate file and export it. After that you can import it in Neighbour and App.js and use it

Comment: In separate file i should include      export MyContext = React.createContext();  ?

Comment: How should i add state in this separate file to this MyContext

Comment: yes, you should write `export const MyContext  = React.createContext()` and then import it like `import { MyContext } from 'path/to/contextfile'`

Comment: export const MyContext = React.createContext('country')  ?? I imported it in both app.js and neighbour.js

Comment: does it help or you are still facing issues

Comment: Ya now its working fine after adding import React from 'react'; in my Context.js file